# Making dynamically created textfield searchable in xml

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, dynamic, textfield

I recently posted a question on this same project that was helpfully answered by walkietokyo. [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14761667/dynamically-creating-multiple-textboxes-that-are-populated-with-xml-data)

So my new question is using that solution to make the text sprites searchable.
So in this case, you could click on any of the dynamic text fields created, the as3 would match up the contents of that specific textfield to data in an xml, upon doing that, it would pick up another node from within the container of nodes for each part of the xml (for instance

```
<Searchtext Wordlookup="chris cheeser">
<location>1</location>
<Name>chris cheeser</Name>
</Searchtext>
```

so it would notice that the textfield I clicked is filled with chris cheeser, it would then match that with my Wordlookup, and identify the location, and match that with my movieclip of the same name)

my current as3 looks like this:

```
private function XMLLoader(e:Event):void
    {
        xmlData = new XML(e.target.data);
        ParseList(xmlData);

    }

    private function ParseList(nameData:XML):void
    {
     var nameList:XMLList = nameData.Searchtext.Name;
//       var textContainer:Sprite = new Sprite();
     this.addChild(textContainer);

     for each (var nameElement:XML in nameList){
//       var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
     format.font = "Arial MT";
     format.size = 22;
     format.color = 0x006699;
     var currTextField:TextField = new TextField();
     currTextField.defaultTextFormat = format;
     currTextField.appendText(nameElement.text() + "\n");
     currTextField.y= 1297 + textContainer.height;
     currTextField.height = 40;
     currTextField.width = 280;
     currTextField.x= 88;
     currTextField.selectable = false;
     textContainer.addChild(currTextField);
     trace(nameElement.text());

       }

    }

    private function onTextClick(e:Event):void 
    {
    var currTextField:TextField = e.target as TextField;

    if (SearchHolder != null){
         TweenMax.to((this["$" + SearchHolder]), 1, {removeTint:true});
        }   
          var resultZ:String = xmlData.Searchtext.(@Wordlookup == currTextField.text.toLowerCase).location.toString()
     SearchHolder = resultZ ? resultZ : "Try again";
        trace(resultZ);
     TweenMax.to(["$" + SearchHolder], 1, {tint:0x00ffcc});
    trace("This name was clicked:", currTextField.text);

    }
```

all that is commented out was placed outside the function, both resultZ and SearchHolder, have been identified as strings publicly, but I keep having an issue with the line that defines the var resultZ (I know this through hours of fiddling trying to figure it out) Right now my trace for resultZ produces nothing, which tells me it has something to do with currTextfield, as I have an identical function set up with an input field that still works.
Any help would be appreciated, but try to be descriptive, I'm still learning!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have missed the parenthesis on the `toLowerCase()` method.

Try this:

```
var resultZ:String = xml.Searchtext.(@Wordlookup == currTextField.text.toLowerCase())[0].location[0].toString();
```

Alternatively, instead of duplicating the name as both a node and an attribute, you can use E4X in a similar way to filter out nodes based on the *content of its child nodes*, like this:

```
var resultZ:String = xml.Searchtext.(Name == currTextField.text)[0].location[0].toString();
```

In the latter case, you could omit the `Wordlookup` attribute from your xml document. (Unless, of course, it is being used for other purposes.)

---

Also note that I added `[0]` after the search and location parameters. This is because in E4X, each "drilldown" produces an `XMLList`, which is an array of nodes. By specifying an accessor like `[0]` you can make sure to select only the first result in case there was multiple nodes matching the same criteria. This may not be the desired outcome, but it's important to keep in mind since omitting it can yield surprising results.

Say, for example, that there's two people in your xml document both called "chris cheeser" which are associated with locations 1 and 5. Without specifying that you only want to select one of these, the same code above (but omitting the `[0]` accessors) would yield the result "15".

However, using the `[0]` accessor will always select the first node matching the description, so if there is a chance that you may have non-unique names, you may have to consider using truly unique identifiers in some way.

Comment: So I have narrowed it down to a specific issue. I implemented your answer, but it's not completely fixed. I get no errors, but the flash isn't matching up the targeted text field's output to anything in the xml. It traces the targeted text field's output with no issues, so I am not sure why this is occurring, Everything matches up in spelling and type case. Maybe it's because the text fields are sprite created, and that may make it hard for a string to search? (that's a complete guess there). I REALLY appreciate all your help, you've been extremely helpful!!

Comment: Try to think about only the exact code required to do what you want. Is there something you missed? Is there something off about the structure of your XML? [Here, you'll find a slightly modified version of the code](http://pastebin.com/bKbLuUCG) I provided for your last question which contains _only_ the code for acquiring the name from a text field and using it to search the XML document.

Comment: I didnt even see this till now. I have to thank you so much for continuously helping me. I am back around to this section after taking a break, and implemented your suggestions. Even though the spelling and all matches up, the location node still comes back null (even though the name node does not). I can't seem to figure out why.